# no view in autocomplete plugin of jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am searching in the database for some items and got a json response.

But i didn't know, which part of my autocomplete didnt work
I got this Output from item when i make console.log(item):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [objektnummer] => 14720
        [anschrift1] => Frau
        [anschrift2] => xxxx
        [strasse] => Bucxxx
        [plz] => 8xxx
        [ort] => Pxxxx
        [projektstatus] => 3
        [erstellungsdatum] => 2014-03-16 12:15:12
        [fertigstellungsdatum] => 2014-03-14
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [objektnummer] => 14778
        [anschrift1] => 

        [anschrift2] => MFH + TG
        [strasse] => Gedxxx
        [plz] => 8xxx
        [ort] => Ascxxx
        [projektstatus] => 1
        [erstellungsdatum] => 2014-02-05 12:15:12
        [fertigstellungsdatum] => 2014-01-02
    )

)
```

Where is my mistake? The response from the php search is correkt. So also the ajax with the url works fine

```
$( "#qObject" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ){
        $.ajax({
            url: $( "#spanqObject" ).data( "url" )
        }).success(function(item){
            console.log(item);
            response(function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.anschrift2,
                    value: item.anschrift2
                }
            });

        }).error(function(){
            console.log("Mist");
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.anschrift2 + " aka " + ui.item.objektnummer :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
    }
});
```

Comment: create a fiddle if you can.

Comment: I do not understand what is your problem. Please be more specific.

Comment: I dont get a list with the searchresults

Comment: what are the console.log telling you?

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what you are trying to do. I suppose you are trying to use autocomplete to load data from a remote location, populate the dropdown, then select a value? Looks like you are using PHP. Have you tried [PHP Autocomplete](http://phpautocomplete.com/examples/loading-remote-data-via-ajaxjsonp/) instead?

```
<?php
$pac = new C_PhpAutocomplete('remote_data');
$pac -> load_remote_data('http://example.com/sample_remote_data.php');
$pac -> display();
?>
<input id="remote_data" type="hidden" />
```

sample_remote_data.php should contain your data array with json encode.

```
<?php
echo json_encode(Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [objektnummer] => 14720
        [anschrift1] => Frau
        [anschrift2] => xxxx
        [strasse] => Bucxxx
        [plz] => 8xxx
        [ort] => Pxxxx
        [projektstatus] => 3
        [erstellungsdatum] => 2014-03-16 12:15:12
        [fertigstellungsdatum] => 2014-03-14
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [objektnummer] => 14778
        [anschrift1] => 

        [anschrift2] => MFH + TG
        [strasse] => Gedxxx
        [plz] => 8xxx
        [ort] => Ascxxx
        [projektstatus] => 1
        [erstellungsdatum] => 2014-02-05 12:15:12
        [fertigstellungsdatum] => 2014-01-02
    )

));
?>
```